# Not able to execute eksctl

Tags: kubernetes, eksctl

I am new to kubernetes, today i installed eksctl in EC2 server with Amazon linux 2 OS.

But getting error as "-bash: /usr/local/bin/eksctl: cannot execute binary file", while running the eksctl.

Steps I followed from the link "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eksctl.html"

1. curl --silent --location "https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/latest/download/eksctl_$(uname -s)_amd64.tar.gz" | tar xz -C /tmp
2. sudo mv /tmp/eksctl /usr/local/bin
3. eksctl version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command instead for step 1:

```
curl --silent --location "https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/latest/download/eksctl_$(uname -s)_arm64.tar.gz" | tar xz -C /tmp
```

All that's different is I replaced `amd64` with `arm64`, since I'm guessing your OS is running on that architecture instead. You can check with `uname -m`:

```
$ uname -m
arm64
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works.  $ uname -m return as aarch64